# TSQL - latest entry

Tags: t-sql

I have a contract table with id and index_id where the max index_id per id represents the latest entry. How could i get the latest contract in tsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the latest index id (contract) for each id then you could use:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(INDEX_ID) AS Latest_Index
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 whatever_fields_you_want_from_contract_record
FROM ContractTable
ORDER BY index_id DESC
```

**Explanation**: The `TOP 1` part limits the number of records returned by the query and the `ORDER BY index_id DESC` part ensures that the returned record(s) will be in DESCending (i.e. biggest value first) order of the index_id value.

**Notes**:
This type of query will work efficiently if there is an index on index_id (or if the table is relatively small).

Also, the query can be expanded to get the latest contract *of a particular kind*, by adding a WHERE clause.  For example  `WHERE CustomerId = 123`